# Trying to save Listview data into Local Settings Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, winjs

im trying to save itemDataSource of a Listview (Windows 8 apps) WinJS, but when i want to convert JSON data to string :

```
_localSettings.values["events"] = JSON.stringify(EventsData);
```

I got this error message :  Circular reference in value argument not supported

Answer (score 1):

Try this method instead of JSON.stringify...

```
new WinJS.Binding.List([1,2,3]).slice()
```

Turns out that slicing a WinJS.Binding.List turns it into a flat array.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely have a circular reference in your JavaScript object (EventsData).

Example: you may have a child object that references its parent object. This is not allowed in JSON since it can't be represented using JSON notation.